# php concatenation - inserting value as class in html

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to adapt a line of php code in a while loop, but something I do breaks how it is written to the html. When I query the datasbase for the value of `my_product` and insert it between the div-tags everything works, like so:

```
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<div>' . the_field('my_product') . '</div>';
}
```

But when I try to query for `my_colour` and insert the value as a `class` inside the first div-tag, the value of `my_colour` is written to the html before the div-tags:

```
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<div class="' . the_field('my_colour') . '"></div>';
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?
(If you are wondering about `the_field()`it is a function belonging to teh plugin Advanced Custom Fields in Wordpress)

Comment: are they both of the same type? i know some variable types don't take kindly to being concatenated in an echo.

Comment: @Jester that might be it. The colour value is actually selected from a dropdown meny. The product is plain text. Do you have an idea how I could attempt getting the colour value to work?

Comment: posted suggestion as answer, i will update it as neccesary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to figure out the type of the variable first. these 2 methods might help to figure out the type

```
print_r(the_field('my_colour'));
```

and

```
echo gettype(the_field('my_colour'));
```

when you know the variable you should be able to convert it to a string.

Correct answer based on the findings of pastic:

```
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $the_query->the_post();
    $colour = get_field('my_colour');
    echo '<div class="' . $colour  . '"></div>';
}
```

Comment: `print_r` prints "plateplum", which is my class for plum colour.
`echo gettype` prints "plateplumNULL"
in this image one can see how the value is paired with a label when set: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/55892413/null.png

Comment: updated the answer based on your comment. I'm still not sure exactly what kind of variable it is ;') but for now this should work anyway i think.

Comment: Thanks. It's strange though because the only thing that happens with the updated code is that nothing at all (colourwise) gets written to the html. Just the divtags and the empty class parenthesis. Previously that class was printed outside the divtag, now it is not printed at all to the html. I don't know what is going on.

Comment: Mmm have you turned on error reporting? I could open a chat room if you want tot discuss a bit if you have time

Comment: I just solved it! Found a function `get_field()` in the plugin documentation. This works: `$colour = get_field( 'my_colour' );`
`echo '<div class="' . $colour . '"></div>';` Your help has been very useful and certainly helped me understand how to leverage the get_field() function. How can I give you credit in the system for your assistance? Maybe if you edit your answer above pointing to the additional info in this comment it is okay for me to mark your answer as correct answer? Otherwise I fear it would be misleading.

Comment: haha, I was already thinking it was something with the plugin, I'm not that familiar with wordpress :p I think the fairest way is just to give me an upvote I guess and then write your own answer and accept that, you did fix it yourself in the end ^^ (changed my answer to be correct anyways)